# Why does this Python 2 code generate an "Access to Closed File" error in CrcFile.compare?

Tags: python

This code runs successfully for the first three files but dies with the mentioned error on the first comparison involving the fourth file as the first of the two compared files. I could upload the actual files somewhere but the occupy 392.43 GIGABYTES uncompressed.

Thinking it was actually a misnamed Put of Memory error as the system running the app only has 4GB of total RAM, I have tried manually closing the files in CrcFile.compare as well as reducing its default buffer size to no avail. The code accesses both files involved separately successfully but dies when trying to compare the two files directly.

here is the code:

```
import os
import os.path
from crcmod.predefined import Crc

class CrcFile(file):
    def __init__(self, sourcefile):
        self.path = sourcefile
        self.__crc = ''
        self.length = len(self.path)

    def crc(self, bufferSize = 524288): #512K buffer 1048576): #one megabyte buffer
        if self.__crc == '':
            crc64 = Crc('crc-64')
            with open(self.path, 'rb', bufferSize) as f:
                while True:
                    data = f.read(bufferSize)
                    if data:
                        crc64.update(data)
                    else:
                        break
                self.__crc = crc64.digest()
        return self.__crc

    def compare(self, picture, bufferSize = 1048576): #one megabyte buffer
        if self.length != picture.length:
            return False
        elif self.crc() != picture.crc():
            return False
        diff = False
        with open(self.path, 'rb', bufferSize) as s:
            if diff:
                return False
        with open(picture.path, 'rb', bufferSize) as p:
            if diff:
                return False
            while True:
                sd = s.read(bufferSize)
                pd = p.read(bufferSize)
                if not sd or not pd and (sd or pd):
                    diff = True
                    break
                if sd != pd:
                    diff = True
                    break
                else:
                    return True

def flist(dir):
    cur = ''
    outlist = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(unicode(dir)):
        if cur != root:
            print 'Scanning: ' + root
            cur = root
        for item in files:
            if item[0] != '.' and item.endswith('.tiff') and item.find('_') == -1:
                outlist.append(CrcFile(os.path.join(root, item)))
    return tuple(outlist)

def duplicatecheck(filelist):
    duplicatelist = []
    for fileindex in xrange(0, len(filelist) - 1):
        dupes = []
        for dupindex in xrange(fileindex + 1, len(filelist)):
            print 'Comparing file ' + os.path.basename(filelist[fileindex].path) + ' to ' + os.path.basename(filelist[dupindex].path)
            if filelist[fileindex].compare(filelist[dupindex]):
                dupes.append(filelist[dupindex].path)
        duplicatelist.append((filelist[fileindex].path, tuple(dupes)))
    return tuple(duplicatelist)

def duplicateprocess(duplicatelist):
    for duplicate in duplicatelist:
        print 'the following files are duplicates of ' + duplicate[0]
        for element in duplicate[1]:
            print element

def main():
    duplicateprocess(duplicatecheck(flist('/Volumes/Shared External/Family Photos')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're trying to read from `s` after it's been closed.

```
with open(self.path, 'rb', bufferSize) as s:
    if diff:
        return False             # s is closed here, exiting "with" block
with open(picture.path, 'rb', bufferSize) as p:
    if diff:
        return False
    while True:
        sd = s.read(bufferSize)   # you're trying to read from s here
        pd = p.read(bufferSize)
```

I'm not sure why you'd bother to open the file and then never use it before it's closed.  Since you need both files open, I'd just combine the two into a single `with` statement (and eliminate the extra check of `diff`):

```
if diff:
    return False
with open(self.path, 'rb', bufferSize) as s, open(picture.path, 'rb', bufferSize) as p:
    while True:
        sd = s.read(bufferSize)
        pd = p.read(bufferSize)
```

I think you need at least Python 2.7 to use multiple context managers in a `with`. If you're stuck on an older Python, just nest them:

```
with open(self.path, 'rb', bufferSize) as s:
    with open(picture.path, 'rb', bufferSize) as p:
        while True:                    # note additional level of indent
            sd = s.read(bufferSize)
            pd = p.read(bufferSize)
```

Comment: kindall - I didn't know the two with opens could be combined like that, Thanks.